# How to discover structure of value in PHP returned from library function? Does not behave as expected, seems to return different values for same key

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Have not coded PHP for many years, but trying a wordpress plugin.

I am having a strange problem with some array values returned by a function.

This specific problem does not matter,  the problem really is if dealing with values returned by functions, how do you check the structure returned?

I have an array built with the statement:

```
$args = array(shortcode_atts(OFP_Posts::get_default_args($dev_mode), $atts));
```

and when I pass that array into a static function, I get this strange behaviour:

```
    static function get_recent_posts($args = array()) {

       $dm = $args['date_modified'];
       $jargs = json_encode($args);
       echo "<p>at top, mod date:$dm:</p><p> $jargs</p>";
```

I get a different value for 'date_modified' from the '$dm' variable, to that in the json.  The one in the json is what I would expect.

output from echo:

```
at top, mod date::

[{"dev_mode":"simpl","limit":5,"offset":0,"order":"DESC","orderby":"date","cat":[],"tag":[],"taxonomy":"","post_type":["post"],"post_status":"publish","ignore_sticky":1,"exclude_current":1,"excerpt":false,"length":10,"date":" ","date_relative":"","date_modified":"yes","css":"","cssID":"","css_class":"","before":"","after":""}]
```

Note: $dm seems to be an empty string, and yet "date_modified" is set to "yes".

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. Any suggestions appreciated.

@ADyson suggested using `var_export($args)`   ... which I think has provided the answer. The data returned from `short_code_atts` does not make a simple array.

Thank you @ADyson

```
array ( 0 => (object) array( 'dev_mode' => 'simpl', 'limit' => 5, 'offset' => 0, 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'cat' => array ( ), 'tag' => array ( ), 'taxonomy' => '', 'post_type' => array ( 0 => 'post', ), 'post_status' => 'publish', 'ignore_sticky' => 1, 'exclude_current' => 1, 'excerpt' => false, 'length' => 10, 'date' => ' ', 'date_relative' => '', 'date_modified' => 'yes', 'css' => '', 'cssID' => '', 'css_class' => '', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', ), 'date_modified' => 'maybe: ', )
```

Note: Solved.  Following the suggestion to add var_export, I had all that was needed to fix the errors.  Lesson is data may not be what you expect, and `var_dump` or `var_export` are the ways to check.

Comment: We really need to see some sample data to understand what you're referring to. Give us a `var_export($args);`, and also the output of your `echo` statement to compare with. Maybe even more than one example would really help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. `$dm = $args[0]['date_modified'];` ought to solve your problem, in that case.

Comment: Apologies it should be `$dm = $args[0]->date_modified'` (since it's an object within the outer array, rather than an associative array). Working demo: https://3v4l.org/hdYvc

Answer (score 1):

This answer really came from ADyson.

If picking up PHP either for the first time, or when rusty, and having trouble with arrays or object, use `var_export` or `var_dump` to check the structure is as expected, and see what is going on.